# Signals when new line is drawn

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm working on an indicator that draws a line at pivot high or pivot low. Unfortunately the query is not entirely clear for my Pinescript knowledge. I want to trigger an alert for long or short when a new line is drawn. However, my queries output signals for all lines and are not particularly helpful. Therefore, how can I implement a query with this indicator only once when Pivot high or Pivot low is reached and a new line is drawn.

Here is the indicator

```
//@version=5

indicator("Test 81", overlay=true)

left = input.int(defval=10, title="Left Bars")
right = input.int(defval=1, title="Right Bars")
quick_right = input.int(defval=5, title="Quick Right")
src = input.string(defval="Close",options = ["Close","High/Low"], title = "Source")

pivot_high = src=="Close" ? ta.pivothigh(close,left,right) : ta.pivothigh(high,left,right)
pivot_lows = src=="Close" ? ta.pivotlow(close, left,right) : ta.pivotlow(low,left,right)

quick_pivot_high = src=="Close" ? ta.pivothigh(close,left,quick_right) : ta.pivothigh(high,left,quick_right)
quick_pivot_lows = src=="Close" ? ta.pivotlow(close, left,quick_right) : ta.pivotlow(low, left,quick_right)

level1 = src=="Close" ? ta.valuewhen(quick_pivot_high, close[quick_right], 0) : ta.valuewhen(quick_pivot_high, high[quick_right], 0)
level2 = src=="Close" ? ta.valuewhen(quick_pivot_lows, close[quick_right], 0) : ta.valuewhen(quick_pivot_lows, low[quick_right], 0)
level3 = src=="Close" ? ta.valuewhen(pivot_high, close[right], 0) : ta.valuewhen(pivot_high, high[right], 0)
level4 = src=="Close" ? ta.valuewhen(pivot_lows, close[right], 0) : ta.valuewhen(pivot_lows, low[right], 0)
level5 = src=="Close" ? ta.valuewhen(pivot_high, close[right], 1) : ta.valuewhen(pivot_high, high[right], 1)
level6 = src=="Close" ? ta.valuewhen(pivot_lows, close[right], 1) : ta.valuewhen(pivot_lows, low[right], 1)
level7 = src=="Close" ? ta.valuewhen(pivot_high, close[right], 2) : ta.valuewhen(pivot_high, high[right], 2)
level8 = src=="Close" ? ta.valuewhen(pivot_lows, close[right], 2) : ta.valuewhen(pivot_lows, low[right], 2)

level1_col = close >= level1 ? color.green : color.red
level2_col = close >= level2 ? color.green : color.red
level3_col = close >= level3 ? color.green : color.red
level4_col = close >= level4 ? color.green : color.red
level5_col = close >= level5 ? color.green : color.red
level6_col = close >= level6 ? color.green : color.red
level7_col = close >= level7 ? color.green : color.red
level8_col = close >= level8 ? color.green : color.red

plot(level1, style= plot.style_line, color=level1_col, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
plot(level2, style= plot.style_line, color=level2_col, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
plot(level3, style= plot.style_line, color=level3_col, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
plot(level4, style= plot.style_line, color=level4_col, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
plot(level5, style= plot.style_line, color=level5_col, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
plot(level6, style= plot.style_line, color=level6_col, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
plot(level7, style= plot.style_line, color=level7_col, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)
plot(level8, style= plot.style_line, color=level8_col, show_last=1, linewidth=2, trackprice=true)

level1_col_r = close >= level1 ? "green" : "red"
level2_col_r = close >= level2 ? "green" : "red"
level3_col_r = close >= level3 ? "green" : "red"
level4_col_r = close >= level4 ? "green" : "red"
level5_col_r = close >= level5 ? "green" : "red"
level6_col_r = close >= level6 ? "green" : "red"
level7_col_r = close >= level7 ? "green" : "red"
level8_col_r = close >= level8 ? "green" : "red"
```

Here is my attempt at the query

```
if close[1] >= level1 and level1_col_r == "red" or 
 close[1] >= level2 and level2_col_r == "red"  or 
 close[1] >= level3 and level3_col_r == "red"  or 
 close[1] >= level4 and level4_col_r == "red"  or 
 close[1] >= level5 and level5_col_r == "red"  or 
 close[1] >= level6 and level6_col_r == "red"  or 
 close[1] >= level7 and level7_col_r == "red"  or 
 close[1] >= level8 and level8_col_r == "red" 

    label.new(bar_index, na, "", color=color.red, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.abovebar)

if close[1] >= level1 and level1_col_r == "green" or 
 close[1] >= level2 and level2_col_r == "green"  or 
 close[1] >= level3 and level3_col_r == "green"  or 
 close[1] >= level4 and level4_col_r == "green"  or 
 close[1] >= level5 and level5_col_r == "green"  or 
 close[1] >= level6 and level6_col_r == "green"  or 
 close[1] >= level7 and level7_col_r == "green"  or
 close[1] >= level8 and level8_col_r == "green"
    
    label.new(bar_index, na, "", color=color.green, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.belowbar)
```